# How to tell if a text file is empty using open() instead of fopen()

Tags: c, linux, fopen

If one can use fopen() then the solution is easy:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(path, "r");
fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fp);
```

if size is zero the file is empty.

However what if the requirement was that fopen() cannot be used. Instead, what I have to use is system calls like open():

```
int f = open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );
```

ftell() can only be used with FILE type streams. I've googled this and could not find any solutions.

Comment: You can use the system call `stat`.  Look at the `st_size` member of the stat struct for the size, in bytes.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a C question (standard C does not know about `open`) but a Linux or POSIX one.

You don't necessarily need [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), and you should realize that on Linux some *other* process could write into a file that you have opened.

Then you might get the size of a file using [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) (with the `.st_size` field) and you could get the size of an opened file descriptor using `fstat`

You might also use [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) (it could be used both for setting and querying the current file offset of an opened file descriptor).